# Bounded and unbounded interval

Tags: real-numbers

According to Hoy et al., an interval is bounded if it is impossible to go off to infinity while remaining inside of it and unbounded otherwise.

Using this definition, how do we show that [a,$\infty$) is unbounded?

I do understand that this is an unbounded set since there is no upper bound, but how does this definition fit in?

Comment: What is the precise definition of " to go off to infinity while remaining inside of it"?

Comment: try the sequence $x_n=n+a$.